# Maximal spaning tree to cover at least one edge of each cycle

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, algorithms

sorry for my somewhat confusing headline. I have the following problem: Given a Graph G := (V, E) that has arbitrarily many cycles. G is undirected and weighted. I want to find a minimal subset of E so that for every cycle in the graph at least one edge that is part of the cycle is also contained by the subset of edges. A single edge is not considered a cycle of course (at the problem would be trivial in this case, so a cycle would not be a->b->a for a,b element of V) and the terminology "minimal" is in respect to the weights of E.

My approach was using a maximal spanning tree T := (V, E') (or rather a maximal spanning forest in case the G is not fully connected). The resulting subset should be simply E / E' with the following argumentation:

By removing the biggest (in respect to edge weights) tree of the graph will guarantee that there will not be any circle in the graph with an edge that is not contained in E / E' (otherwise T would have cycles which it obviously can not have). Also with the same "proof" I can say that i can not remove any more edges (otherwise I would create a cycle that is not covered). Removing less edges will result in a "bigger" E / E' which is also not what I want.

However from hidden test cases I know that my algorithm (using the spanning tree) does not work. I however can not imgaine why that is. If anyone could explain my mistake or provide a counter example I would be very glad.

Also note that I am fully aware that the problem can be reduced to set covering however this problem is NP-complete and nothing that should be implemented.

Comment: Your algorithm seems reasonable to me as well. Are you sure that there is no mistake in the implementation?

Comment: I agree with  Misha (provided  E / E' means $E\setminus E’$).